# Modify UIViewController after resumed from background before view is showed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to modify my `UIViewController` after app has been in background and then brought to front again and I want to modify the view before it is showed. How can I do this since `-viewWillAppear:` is not called? Should I in `- application:didBecomeActive` get a reference to the view controller being displayed and then modify the view? It is important that the view is not modified while being visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller can register itself as an observer of the [UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification) notification to react as needed.

---

That alone cannot guarantee that the view is or is not visible.

The UIApplicationDelegate protocol docs state that the notification will be fired after -applicationDidBecomeActive: is called. Depending on what event triggered that call a view may or may not already be visible. For example if the app was suspended due to an incoming call then the view may remain visible while the user declines the call and will still be visible when the app becomes active again.

You probably need to track if the app actually entered the background after becoming inactive to decide what action to take on becoming active again. `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` sounds like the notification you are looking for but that alone won't tell you if the app was interrupted by some event or if the user suspended it by pressing the home button. You'll also need to consider cases where the app may have been suspended, terminated, and is then re-launched.

[Managing App State Changes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW14) in the iOS App Programming Guide is going to be required reading to figure out how you want to respond to the different possible transitions.

Comment: Yep but will the view controller already be visible when this notification is delivered?

Comment: @PeterWarbo sometimes, I've tried to clarify. What sort of behavior is this meant to support though? It seems odd to have a controller behave differently depending on if (or how) the app was resumed vs if the controller was presented due to some in-app event.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. The reason for this is that the user can flip a couple of switches in Settings app and then I need to redraw the UI when user comes back to app. Since I can't animate the redrawing I the UI it will look sloppy so I want to do this before the view is visible. Hopefully it can be done in applicationWillEnterForeground:

Comment: @PeterWarbo sounds like that should work for you. Those settings shouldn't change while your app is just inactive so checking foreground/background transitions should get you the behavior you want.